# Share Menu Screen Position on Mac(Catalyst)

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I created a ShareButton like this:

```swift
struct ShareButton<Content: View>: View {
    var items: [Any]
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: [])
            avc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = UIHostingController(rootView: self).view
            UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.rootViewController?.present(avc, animated: false)
        } label: {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

this can be used like this:

```swift
    ShareButton(items: [someURL]){
        Label("share", systemImage:"square.and.arrow.up")
    }
```

However, on Mac(Catalyst) and iPad the share-menu-popup appears in the wrong place.
It seems that `UIHostingController(rootView: self).view` returns the wrong reference view. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using your ShareButton in a .toolbar() or in a view? If it’s just in a view, I think the code you have should work. If it’s in a toolbar, then you’ve got a problem. This is the best solution I know of: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2020/popovers-from-swiftui-uibarbutton/